# Is there something similar to pseudorandom generators but in the opposite direction?

Tags: cryptography, random

Pseudorandom generators ([PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator)) are functions that takes a random small input (called the Seed) and maps it into much larger output .

However, the mapping process must be unpredictable in order for the PRG to be used securely in cryptography.

My question is: Are there any tool  the does the opposite? i.e. takes a long random string and maps it to a smaller random unpredictable output?

And if not, can we use [s-box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-box) for this purpose?

Comment: A hash function?

Comment: @HSN — what's the use case for this?

Comment: Unless I miss something, you just described a cryptographic hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me a cryptographic hash, such as the SHA family, would do what you are describing. If not perhaps you could clarify your question.

Comment: Correct. Hash functions can actually be used as a *random extractor* (see NIST SP 800-90B). NIST however requires that you put in twice as much entropy as the output of the hash function (to call it fully randomized). Of course, if you already have a well seeded CSPRNG you can just take the amount of bytes you require for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

PRG do not really map something small to something big. Seed and numbers are often of the same size. Also they are not unpredictable but deterministic for a given seed. Only the sequence of numbers the PRG creates is "random".

Anyway, if you need a function where you put in something big and get a smaller result where you can not simply revert the process, you are probably looking for a [hashing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

But maybe you need to tell us more about what you like to do.